# separating numbers into sum of positional digits in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working with **freecodecamp studies** and need to find a way to turn a number into sum of positional digits like **[1234] to [1000,200,30,4]**.
Code looks like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<newArr.length;i++){
    var order = newArr.length-1 - i;
    newArr.splice(i,1,newArr[i]*1e(order));
}
```

Here newArr will be 1234.
**Node gives error: invalid token 1e(order).**
Need some advice how to make it right.

Comment: Exponential notation only works for number literals, you can't put an expression in place of the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the below logic

```js
 var n = 123456;
    n=n.toString();
    var arr = n.split("");
    var b = arr.map(function(x,i) {
       return x * Math.pow(10, (arr.length-i-1));;
    });
    console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = 1234
b = []
while(a>0){
 b.unshift(a%10 * (10 ** b.length))
 a = parseInt(a/10)
}
console.log(b)
```

Comment: This seems to be backwards, but it's nice that you don't have to convert to a string. You could make it match the question with `b.unshift()` instead of `push()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
Number.prototype.padRight = function (n,str) {
    return (this < 0 ? '-' : '') + (Math.abs(this)+ Array(n-String(Math.abs(this)).length+1).join(str||'0'));
}
var digits = "1234"
var tempCounter= digits.length;
var result=[];
for(var i=0;i<digits.length;i++,tempCounter--){
    result.push(parseInt(digits[i]).padRight(tempCounter))
}
console.log(result);
```